# Simplest way to check if optional parameter is omitted?

Tags: programming, data, optional-arguments

Suppose I have a function

`f[x_,y___]:=` (code)

and I want my code to check whether the parameter `y` is omitted. What's the easiest way to do this?

I tried some quick guesses, like `If[y == Null]` and `If[¬ValueQ@y]`, but these didn't work. I was able to use

```
f[x_,y___]:=
Module[{yList},
yList={y};
If[yList == {},(* code *)]
]
```

but surely there is a more elegant method than this clunky one.

Comment: You could just do `{y} === {}`. No need for an intermediate variable.

Comment: Or `f[x_, y___] := If[y === Null, code1, code2]`

Comment: Thank you  @Carl.

Comment: Do you use a default value for `y` when it is not given in the call? Perhaps two definitions of `f` would be more legible? `f[x_] := implementationFunction[x, {}]; f[x_, y_] := implementationFunction[x, y]`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I went with #1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way is to use two different patterns:

```
f[x_]:= single arg code
f[x_,y__]:= double arg code
```